# Detecting network request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When using gems for external services, sometimes I don't know whether a method does a trip to the service or just returns some local computation.

An example - I'm using an image hosting service (Cloudinary) that has a Ruby wrapper for their API. The following command returns a complete URL to a hosted image when providing an image_id:

```
Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url(image_id)
#=> "http://res.cloudinary.com/my_service/image/upload/v1/some_image_id"
```

I'd probably construct that URL manually to skip a HTTP request (if that what's what happens).

So to my question - is there any faster way than digging in the source code or unplugging internet access to detect if network request is made before returning a value?

Comment: Surely. Check the source code.

Comment: Haha, yes of course. Forgot to mention the obvious.

Comment: It does not seem to make a request, but it does [a hell lot of configuration](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/utils.rb#L335) so I would not suggest to just construct the `url` yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudinary is using `RestClient` gem. It allows set global logging.

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client#logging

> To enable logging globally you can:
>
> set RestClient.log with a Ruby Logger, or set an environment variable
>
> to avoid modifying the code (in this case you can use a file name,
>   "stdout" or "stderr"):
>
> $ RESTCLIENT_LOG=stdout path/to/my/program